# batch file reading variable from for loop

Tags: batch-file

I have a small batch script and wondering why is it working like this. The snippets shows a for loop which should look for Rf-Stick1.conf and find the string "type". Futhermore it should write the following value into "TYPE".

It works when i use "echo !TYPE!", but the if statement is not working. Someone knows the problem?

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=: " %%a in ('type "Configs\Rf-Stick1.conf" ^| findstr /ir "^type" 2^>nul') DO set "TYPE=%%a"        

echo !TYPE!
if !TYPE! EQU "RF" echo rf
```

Comment: @MCND's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43935679/2096401) is probably what you need, but also use something like `echo ::!TYPE!::` whenever debugging values so you can see if there are leading/trailing spaces etc. that might be causing problems.

Comment: The `if` statement takes the quotation marks literally and includes them in the comparison; hence you must provide them on both sides of the comparison operator: `if "!TYPE!" EQU "RF" echo rf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the variable `TYPE` contains the value `RF`, then the command

```
if !TYPE! EQU "RF" echo rf
```

is parsed and converted into

```
if RF EQU "RF" echo rf
```

As you can see, you are comparing a string without quotes against a string with quotes, so, they don't match. Try with

```
if "!TYPE!" EQU "RF" echo rf
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `if !TYPE!` is interpreted as `if not TYPE!`
You need to change your if condition so that the effective condition is what you want.

Comment: hmm, well, but if i use %TYPE% instead as i usually do, it doesnt work. Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the output of `echo %TYPE%`